# How use pm2 to deploy an angular2 app in remote server

Tags: node.js, angular, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, pm2

I'm using a CI process to deploy my applications. So, I'm planning build a nodeJS and Angular2 Apps in remote server.

For NodeJS App, I'm using pm2 to start a processo. I'm planning to create an ecosystem an start the native deployment process of pm2 ([link](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/)).

Here is my json file:

```
  {
      name      : "testpm2",
      script    : "../index.js",
      //...,
    }
  ],
  deploy : {
    //...,
    dev : {
      user : "vagrant",
      host : "192.168.56.11",
      ref  : "origin/master",
      repo : "<repo - git>",
      path : "/var/lib/development",
      "post-deploy" : "npm install && pm2 startOrRestart /var/lib/development/ecosystem.json --env dev",
      env  : {
        NODE_ENV: "dev"
      }
    }
  }
```

So, everything is fine. Node behaviour is pretty cool!!!

So, my question is: can I use the same process to start an Angular2 Application? I'm using angular2-cli, then, I start the process using **ng build** and **ng serve** calls. It is possible to do that with pm2 deployment, as the same of NodeJS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you installed the angular-cli package in the remote server, you can make a `ng build && ng serve` in the `post-deploy` entry.

Comment: Got it! Maybe the process still beying in session while the serve is running. I think I have use ng build and ng serve in pm2 with npm start command.

Comment: but what about the script tag? Should I remove this for angular2?

Comment: yeah totally, just put the deploy part since its the post-deploy that is used.